# pgAdmin crashes or freezes when big MATERIALIZED VIEWs are refreshing

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, materialized-view

I'm using pgAdmin III v1.22.1 on Windows 7 to connect to a PostgreSQL server version 9.4.8 on Red Hat.

We have scripts to `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEWS` during the night.
When they are refreshing, I can't connect to pgAdmin III. It just freezes. It seems that it tries to query some locked objects.

When the materialized views finishes refreshing, I am then able to log in via pgAdmin.

When the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view` is done, the above query is run and pgAdmin unfreezes.

Is there a way to prevent pgAdmin from freezing when `MATERIALIZED VIEWS` are refreshing?

Comment: How much time it takes normally to refresh that view ? Maybe it only seems to freeze but its only waiting for ending the query.

Comment: It can take many hours to refresh some matviews. pgAdmin shouldn't freeze when queries are running in the background.

Comment: I've edited the question to show an extract from `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`

Comment: It seems that it's a [known bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B3659E858@ntex2010i.host.magwien.gv.at). I hope it will be resolved in a future release.

Answer (score 4):

I seems that it's a [known bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B3659E858%40ntex2010i.host.magwien.gv.at).
I'm answering to my own question with this workaround.

If you use PostgreSQL 9.4+, one workaround is to use `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`.

From [PostgreSQL's manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html):

> **CONCURRENTLY**
>
> Refresh the materialized view without locking out concurrent selects on the materialized view. Without this option a refresh which
>   affects a lot of rows will tend to use fewer resources and complete
>   more quickly, but could block other connections which are trying to
>   read from the materialized view. This option may be faster in cases
>   where a small number of rows are affected.
>
> This option is only allowed if there is at least one UNIQUE index on the materialized view which uses only column names and includes all
>   rows; that is, it must not index on any expressions nor include a
>   WHERE clause.

You just need to add an `UNIQUE INDEX` to your materialized view and to refresh it `CONCURRENTLY`:

```sql
-- add index (do it only once per matview)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON very_big_matview (id);
-- refresh concurrently
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY very_big_matview;
```

But it does not prevent other users from running long refreshes which hangs my pgAdmin.